# Otimizar a forma de remover classes de elementos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma sequências de linhas para remover classes de vários elementos. Existiria uma maneira mais sofisticada, talvez com menos código para realizar o mesmo que o código abaixo?

`$(document).find('.control-corpo').removeClass('control-corpo');
$(document).find('.control-container').removeClass('control-container');
$(document).find('.control-button').removeClass('control-button');
$(document).find('.control-content').removeClass('control-content');
$(document).find('.control-scroll').removeClass('control-scroll');
$(document).find('.control-delay').removeClass('control-delay');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode escrever uma função que otimize isso, deixando o código mais limpo.

```
function removeClass(className) {
    $(document).find("." + className).removeClass(className);
}

removeClass('control-corpo');
removeClass('control-container');
removeClass('control-button');
removeClass('control-content');
removeClass('control-scroll');
removeClass('control-delay');
```

Importante também adicionar essa função na estrutura do projeto de forma que ela não fique desacoplada ou largada. Dentro de um Helpers ou algo parecido.

Comment: Isso resolve! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Faça como a resposta do @Vandemberg Lima sugeriu, mas já que as classes possuem o mesmo prefixo `control-`, para ficar ainda mais otimizado, você pode enviar para a função apenas o nome que vier após o prefixo, e ainda usar a forma curta de `.find()`:

```js
function rClass(c){
   $('.control-'+c, document).removeClass('control-'+c);
}

function exemplo(){
   rClass('corpo');
   rClass('container');
   rClass('button');
   rClass('content');
   rClass('scroll');
   rClass('delay');
}
```

```css
[class^='control']{
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-corpo">corpo</div>
<div class="control-container">container</div>
<div class="control-button">button</div>
<div class="control-content">content</div>
<div class="control-scroll">scroll</div>
<div class="control-delay">delay</div>
<br>
<button onclick="exemplo()">Remover classes</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma também é utilizando `.call()`, onde você envia os nomes das classes via array para a função. Deste modo você só chama a função uma única vez e remove todas as classes especificadas:

```js
function rClass(a){
   for(var c of a)
   $('.control-'+c, document).removeClass('control-'+c);
}

function exemplo(){
   rClass.call(null,
      ['corpo','container','button','content','scroll','delay']
   );
}
```

```css
[class^='control']{
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-corpo">corpo</div>
<div class="control-container">container</div>
<div class="control-button">button</div>
<div class="control-content">content</div>
<div class="control-scroll">scroll</div>
<div class="control-delay">delay</div>
<br>
<button onclick="exemplo()">Remover classes</button>
```

Comment: essa é uma solução fantástica.

Comment: esse loop ` for(var c of a)` não funciona no IE não né?

Comment: Funciona não mas pode-se usar um for normal tb.

Comment: Gostaria de ver uma solução com esse for normal.

Comment: Segue: https://jsfiddle.net/oaojny2u/1/

Comment: Bom, muito bom! Está funcionando até no IE7.Thx.

Comment: rs.. eu foco mais o IE9+ (e olhe lá)... se alguém usa algo antes disso, está muito atrasado